# Reflection on a Clear Globe

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Here is my problem.

I have a clear Globe that is a Christmas ornament. It has a little abscrat nativity scene inside. All is good, my issue comes in when I attempt to add a reflection to the outside of the orb. It looks very fake, How would I go about adding a transparent reflection that helps the globe take shape to indicate that it is truly a globe?

I am using Photoshop CS 5.1

Comment: Post a screenshot if possible

Comment: Photos of real glass balls: http://www.pickchur.com/2011/05/unique-upside-down-photography-through-glass-marble/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A screenshot would really help.

But for first advice, search for tutorials like [this](http://www.lunacore.com/photoshop/tutorials/tut009.htm) one. Or search for images that looks like you want it. For me words like "globe", "sphere", "glass ball" or "orb" where good.